# Adding where clause after HANA placeholders in SQLAlchemy

Tags: sqlalchemy, placeholder, hana

I'm trying to construct a query like this:

```
SELECT "Inventory".item_id, "Inventory".region
FROM "Inventory" ('PLACEHOLDER' = ('$$P_Param$$', '0')) 
WHERE "Inventory".region = :region_1
```

My select statement is adding the HANA placeholders at the end though:

```
 select_stmt = select(
            inventory.item_id,
            inventory.region
        ).suffix_with(placeholders).where(inventory.region== 'USA')



SELECT "Inventory".item_id, "Inventory".region
FROM "Inventory" 
WHERE "Inventory".region = :region_1 ('PLACEHOLDER' = ('$$P_Param$$', '0'))
```

How do I suffix the from clause with the placeholders and add the where clause afterwards?

```
class Inventory(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'Inventory'
    __table_args__ = {'schema': '_SYS_BIC'}

    date = Column(DateTime, primary_key=True)
    item_id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)  
    region = Column(String)
    
    placeholder = "('PLACEHOLDER' = ('$$P_Param$$', '0'))"
```

Answer (score 0):

The [SAP Hana](https://github.com/SAP/sqlalchemy-hana) dialect does not seem to support placeholders.

As you saw [`suffix_with`](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/orm/query.html#sqlalchemy.orm.query.Query.suffix_with) does exactly what it says, it appends a suffix to the full query.

Without dialect support, you could try using a [`from_statement`](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/orm/query.html#sqlalchemy.orm.query.Query.from_statement) with [`text`](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/core/sqlelement.html#sqlalchemy.sql.expression.text) which will allow to load what you need using your own SQL statements.